# JENKINS Permissions file Need to backup

Tags: jenkins

quick question:

are Jenkins user permission are stored in a file somewhere?

I would like to backup that file. Just in case server crash.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be prepared in case jenkins server crash, I suggest you backup all the `*.xml` files inside your **$JENKINS_HOME** since thost `*.xml` files are really important config files that are essential to restore your jenkins in future. I am using `rsync` to do the backup:

```
echo "Start rsync...."
rsync -zarv --include="*/" --include-from="include.txt" --exclude="*" path_to_your_jenkins_home the_target_directory_you_want_to_store_the_backup
```

the `include.txt` contains below content.

```
.xml
```

BTW, you can setup an daily job to execute above shell script and do the backup.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

Jenkins permissions  are stored in a config file in your host machine where the server is configure.
You can find it in $JENKINS_HOME as told by mainframer,by default the location is

```
  /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/your_job_name/config.xml
```

If you edit the permissions here it will be reflected on the server.

Also if you want to back up your configuration, Jenkins has a lot of plugins to help you out.

1). [JobConfigHistory](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/JobConfigHistory+Plugin)

Track any changes in config files and revert them back immediately.

2). [PeriodicBackup](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/PeriodicBackup+Plugin)

Takes periodic backups like a cron job.

Please let me know if it helps.